# Sort articles based on time and not date in nanoc

Tags: ruby, nanoc

i am new to ruby and nanoc. I am trying to sort articles based on time. So I get more accurate results on my blog.

This is what I am using in my `sorted_articles_time.rb` file under `/helpers/`

```
def sorted_articles_time
  articles.sort_by do |a|
    attribute_to_time(a[:time])
  end.reverse
end
```

But then I get the error

```
NoMethodError: private method `sorted_articles_time' called for #<Nanoc::Site:0x007fd93b0a3f40>
```

What am I doing wrong ? And is there a way to overwrite the existing sorted_articles method ?

Thanks

UPDATE: I already have it initiated in the rake file. So I think my rake file is fine here.

```
time1 = Time.new
@time =  time1.inspect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling `@site.sorted_article_times`? If so, leave off the `@site` part. Helpers are intended to be called as functions, not as methods on `@site`.

Comment: Ah, right. But now that i removed that. I get an error


`ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with Time failed`

Comment: Then I am guessing some article’s `:time` attribute is nil.

Comment: Ah i got it. Parsed a new time object and sorted the articles based on that. Thanks.

If you got time. can you help me answer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866141/how-to-generate-pages-for-each-tag-in-nanoc

Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

Use a scrope from your model. Check this active[active_record_querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) this is the best place to sort your articles.

Comment: That is not a nanoc answer.